# How do I use my MyMonero wallet via the Monero Core GUI?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery, mymonero, monero-wallet-gui

I have been using a [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com/) wallet for quite a while. Can I start using that wallet from within the [Monero Core GUI](https://getmonero.org/2016/12/22/monero-core-gui-beta-released.html)? How do I do that?

Comment: That would be great ..... but it's currently impossible to even log in to MyMonero.com just to get the keys!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The MyMonero wallets use a different type of mnemonic: 13 words instead of 25 words. The Monero Core GUI (or the CLI) doesn't support restoring a wallet from a 13 word mnemonic seed. Therefore, you'll need to go **via the keys**.

1. In [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com/), once logged in, click on the <kbd>Accounts</kbd> drop-down menu, and choose <kbd>Account Details</kbd>:

[image]

2. Next, the "**Review Account Details**" page will be shown, containing the following 3 items (copy the text values from your browser):

[image]

3. Once you have the above information, you can move on and **import them into a new wallet using the CLI utility** `monero-wallet-cli`, which is shipped as part of the Monero Core GUI software. Locate the CLI utility on your system. Depending on your platform, it will be in a different location. For example, on macOS, assuming you've installed the software in the Applications folder, the CLI utility will be at `/Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monero-wallet-cli`.
4. Once you know where the CLI utility resides, open a **Terminal** (macOS) or **Command Prompt** (Windows). Create a suitable directory for the wallet, and start the import process with `/Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-keys mymonero.wallet`:

[image]

5. If you don't have a daemon active yet, ignore those errors for now. Start up the Monero Core GUI, and choose the option "**Open a wallet from file**". Navigate to the directory (e.g. `mymonero`) where you performed the above step. Select the file `monero.wallet.keys` and click <kbd>Open</kbd>. After you've entered the password and clicked on <kbd>OK</kbd>, your MyMonero wallet will now start synchronizing against the daemon (assuming it is running, or if you pointed to an external node at the Welcome screen). Once completed, check your address on the Receive page:

[image]

Note that on the **Settings** page of the GUI, clicking on the <kbd>Show seed</kbd> button won't do anything, because the format of your wallet's seed is imcompatible with the 25-word style mmemonic used in the official CLI and GUI.

Comment: how do you do this in windows please?

Comment: Posted a walkthrough for Windows as a new answer below.

Comment: You can skip the CLI and use the GUI directly with the GUI v2 and later. Instructions: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/how-to-restore-a-monero-wallet-from-private-keys/3776#3776

Answer (score 3):

On a **Windows** platform, the steps are mostly similar, except for 3 and 4. Let's assume we downloaded the ZIP-file `monero.gui.win.x64.beta.zip` from the [official website](https://getmonero.org/2016/12/22/monero-core-gui-beta-released.html) straight to the Desktop.

Unzip the ZIP-file on your desktop itself. This should give you a directory `monero-wallet-gui` on your desktop, which contains (among many other files):

- `monero-wallet-gui.exe`
- `monero-wallet-cli.exe`

Open a Command Prompt: Start menu → Type in `cmd` → Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Next, we'll first create a suitable directory for the wallet. We'll do this directly in the location where the GUI stores them too. Next, we'll start the import process using the CLI utility `monero-wallet-cli.exe`. Type in the commands as you see them below, replacing the address and keys with yours obviously:

[image]

After this, start the GUI by double-clicking on `monero-wallet-gui.exe`, or via a shortcut you may have created elsewhere. Type in a remote node, such as `node.moneroworld.com`, and choose **Open a wallet from file**. Navigate to the file `mymonero.wallet.keys`, select it, and click on <kbd>Open</kbd>.

[image]

After you type in your password, your wallet should start synchronizing against the blockchain.

Comment: After this my balance shows 0 in with GUI and CLI. I have tried many times and am definitely using the proper view and spend keys.

Comment: @B.D. Are you running a daemon and are you sure it's fully synced?

Answer (score 0):

Your MyMonero wallet can be imported into most wallets, including the official GUI and CLI. Start by collecting your MyMonero info. Then select a wallet to restore your account with.

## Collecting MyMonero Info

You need to log in to MyMonero to collect the information necessary to restore your account.

If you prefer not to log in, you can use [luigi's tool as instructed here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/6887/42) to acquire your spend keys manually. Then skip to your specific wallet instructions.

You can log in, click on `Account`, and then click on `Account details` as shown below.

[image: MyMonero select account info]

A screen will appear with your information. Keep this handy for restoring your wallet. It will look similar to the image below.

[image: MyMonero review account details]

Keep the login words handy too. Some wallets allow you to restore your wallet using the 13-word MyMonero password directly.

## GUI/CLI

Follow the guide located on this page: https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/restore_from_keys.html

If you know when you first received funds in the wallet, add a restore height to save a lot of sync time (strongly recommended). [Click here](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/m2049r/xmrwallet/util/RestoreHeight.java) to see a list that Monerujo maintains. Search for a line with `blockheight.put` such as the following:

`blockheight.put("2018-01-01", 1477201L);`

You are interested in the last number, in this case `1477201`. Drop the L and add it to the GUI. By undertaking this step, you could save many minutes or hours of sync time.

## [Monerujo](https://monerujo.io)

Monerujo is an open-source android wallet.

Open the wallet, click the `+` icon in the lower right, and then click `Restore wallet from private keys`.

[image]

Insert the MyMonero strings.

If you know when you first received funds, add that date to the restore height. Moneujo supports you typing a date to estimate the specific restore height.

## [Cake Wallet](https://cakewallet.io/)

Cake Wallet is an iOS wallet that features functionality for restoring your 13 word MyMonero-style mnemonic seed directly.

Press the wallet name at the top, which will bring you the to the list of wallets. Click on `Restore Wallet` at the bottom.

[image]

This will bring you to restore screen. Press `From seed`. You can optionally restore from keys if desired.

[image]

Fill in the fields. If you know the time you first received Monero in the wallet, then I strongly recommend you set it as the `Restore from date`. This will save you minutes or hours of sync time.

[image]

## [X Wallet](https://xwallet.tech/)

X Wallet is an iOS wallet that features functionality for restoring your wallet from keys. More screenshots and info coming soon.