# Why not include a README.TXT in the GUI Wallet Beta zip file?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Consider adding a README.TXT to the Monero GUI wallet that contains some helpful hints on getting started, it could even just be a handful of URLs.

It'd be a bonus if it explained some of the executables in the package and which does what.

I'm coming to this because I've installed the GUI wallet in Windows and imported a wallet but can't get the daemon to start.  I'm thinking that the dameon is equal to monerod.exe but went looking for a README to verify.

Comment: Here are some URL's of open tabs I have going now as I start to understand the GUI wallet:

https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-use-the-monero-gui-wallet

https://getmonero.org/2016/12/22/monero-core-gui-beta-released.html

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5q6rls/video_ultimate_step_by_step_import_restore/

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/how-do-i-use-my-mymonero-wallet-via-the-monero-core-gui

Answer (score 1):

No particular reason. It'd need... someone to write one, someone to PR one, someone to include it in the release. fluffypony can take care of the third. The first one is the most time consuming. I think the release notes that are already published on github could be usefully included. But anyone's free to add a "my first few steps with the GUI" introduction to the GUI and PR it to https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core. If you dream of being a Monero contributor, now's your xhance :) And if not, somebody else will do it eventually. But yes, a good idea :)