# Can I sweep funds in mymonero to another wallet?

Tags: mymonero, sweep-transaction

I have too little funds in MyMonero. Is there a way I can sweep those funds into another wallet?

I'm guessing I tried doing this once before, but it didn't like me sending all because it wanted some for fees. I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot transfer to another wallet with different address without a transfer fee. However, if you want to use a CLI or GUI wallet you can do so.

If using a GUI follow this guide:

[How do I use my MyMonero wallet via the Monero Core GUI?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/how-do-i-use-my-mymonero-wallet-via-the-monero-core-gui?rq=1)

or using a CLI:

[If I saved my view key and spend key can I recover my wallet if my mnemonic seed is lost?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/55/if-i-saved-my-view-key-and-spend-key-can-i-recover-my-wallet-if-my-mnemonic-seed?rq=1)

FYI. Transfer fee has decreased since the last hard forked in April 15.

Comment: Alright, understanding the "monero bank" conceptually is like learning how git works for the first time. I don't need to "transfer" all funds from My Monero. I own the address and keys, which means I can view/spend funds connected to them in any wallet any time. I just happened to be viewing the cumulative transactions on My Monero. Now, I am viewing them in CLI. The phrase "backing up" is almost meaningless; it's already backed up in the blockchain. We're merely "viewing our part/account" with the address and keys. Awesome, thank you.

Comment: Your correct. In the future,  if your monero/xmr accumulates to a large sum it is a good practice to put them on a different wallet address(cold wallet) from your a light wallet such as MyMonero. Take caution also of using other wallets that don't provide you with a private key.