# How to use my 13 word MyMonero mnemonic seed with the GUI/CLI without accessing MyMonero?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed, mymonero

It seems that MyMonero.com has been hacked and a lot of XMRs are gone. Mine probably included. I want to check my wallet and send out everything as soon as possible.

I setup full node, synced blockchain but when it comes to seed recovery, it needs 25 words recovery seed or keys. **I have only 13 words recovery seed** from mymonero (from hopefully not hacked version) and no keys.

I cannot get keys from mymonero.com (i will never login there anymore).

How can i solve this situation?

Thank you and **DO NOT LOG INTO MYMONERO.COM (never) again!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done as follows:

1. Go to this page: https://github.com/luigi1111/xmr.llcoins.net/
2. Click on `Clone or download` and download the ZIP file. This ZIP file can be used offline if needed.
3. In addition, you can verify the files by following the steps in the README: https://github.com/luigi1111/xmr.llcoins.net/#xmrllcoinsnet
4. Open `addresstests.html`
5. Put the 13 word MyMonero seed in box `1. Mnemonic Seed`
6. Click on `Gen 2.`
7. Click on `Gen 3 & 4.`
8. Click on `Gen 5.`
9. Click on `Gen 6.`
10. Click on `Gen 7.`
11. Now that you have your private view key + private spend key + public address, proceed with this guide:

[How to restore a Monero wallet from Private Keys](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/how-to-restore-a-monero-wallet-from-private-keys)

---

For the CLI, first perform step 1 to 10 as well. Thereafter, perform the following steps:

**[1]** Browse to the directory `monero-wallet-cli` is located.

**[2a]** On Windows, open a new command prompt from the same directory as `monero-wallet-cli.exe`. This is done by first making sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files and subsequently doing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd>. It will give you an option to "Open command window here". If you're using Windows 10, it'll, most likely, give you an option to open the Powershell.

**[2b]** On Linux and Mac OS X, open a new terminal from the same directory as `monero-wallet-cli`

**[3a]** On Windows, type the following command in the command prompt:

`monero-wallet-cli.exe --generate-from-keys <wallet-name>`

If that doesn't work in the Powershell, type:

`.\monero-wallet-cli.exe --generate-from-keys <wallet-name>`

If that doesn't work either in the Powershell, type:

`./monero-wallet-cli.exe --generate-from-keys <wallet-name>`

**[3b]** On Linux and Mac OS X, type the following command in the terminal:

`./monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-keys <wallet-name>`

**[4]** Enter your private spend key, private view key, and public address, and it will "recreate" your MyMonero wallet.

P.S. Luigi1111 is a core-team member of Monero.

Comment: Great solution, however be weary of entering your mnemonic code anywhere online, even on a search engine. It can easily be taken and someone may transfer your coins to an undisclosed account. You can also try to use the restore wallet option on Monero GUI - 0.11.1.0 Helium Hydra, using your public, private and spend key on your computer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However let me add one more security step - after step 3 disconnect internet and open that addresstests.html file in anonymous window. After keys generation close browser. It ensures no evil js on page (or as a browser extension) can send your keys out of your computer.