# Several basic questions about Monero and maybe crypto currency minning in general

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining-pools, mining, mymonero

I'am very new at crypto currency minning so you could find my questions very basics. Feel free to downvote, no hard feelings.

**Why did I choose Monero**

As far as I know Monero is private, secure and untraceable however the most valuable feature for me is you can mine Monero using **CPU** and **GPU**. I can't afford GPU but lets say I can afford electricity.

**You won't do much with CPU minning**

That's probably right, but better something than nothing, so far I'm not thinking at this as a bussiness.

**What I did**

After reading about Monero [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5zgail/rmonero_newcomers_please_read_everything_you_need/) I decided to create my wallet on [mymonero](https://mymonero.com/#/?). What I got: **13 words mnemonic phrase** (private login key) and a **95 characters** line which I guess is a sort of **encrypted unique ID**, for instance "**jHcjtyj767ehh29837**..."
So far I have created my first Monero wallet with 0.00 Monero on it. Next step is to start minnnig some Moneroj.

**Start minning**

For some punctual reason I couldn't get my Linux guest machine available for minning so checked out for a way to use Windows and I found [Monero 0.11.1.0 "Helium Hydra"](https://getmonero.org/2017/10/27/monero-0.11.1.0-released.html) which is a client for Windows. It allows you to create a wallet and also do "**Solo minning**". But it asks to do a new wallet, why can't I use the first one created on the website? Also instead of giving me a 13 words mnemonic phrase I got a **25 words** one. There wasn't a 95 characters line also. Looks clear to me, *using the web site you are storing your wallet on the website and using Monero desktop client you are storing your wallet on your own storage*. But, if it is a client **why just can't point to the web wallet (first one created) address** and start minning?

[image: Solo minning]

Image above doesn't shows any field to point the web wallet address. So here comes my first "mixed" question:

***1- Are Moneroj from first wallet somehow different from the Moneroj inside second wallet? Can I combine then and make it only one wallet?***

My first question gives my the chance to talk about my second question and it's related with Pool minning.

**Pool minning**

As I could see the Monero Windows client only allows you to do Solo minning, not Pool minning. Let's say I start doing Pool minning on any of [these](http://moneropools.com/) pools.

***2- Can I point to my first web wallet? If I start minning on for instance pool1.com and then decide to change to pool2.com, the earned Moneroj from first pool are still there?***

I have plenty of questions but this should be enough for a beginner.

Comment: It is best if you only ask one question per post. As it stands, your post is quite broad because you are asking several, unrelated, questions. I suggest you split your question into several, focused, questions.

Comment: Regarding your question on how to open your mymonero wallet in the GUI: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/how-to-use-my-13-word-mymonero-mnemonic-seed-with-the-gui-cli-without-accessing